Why was my suggested edit of a docker-related question rejected?
Recently, I got my suggested edit rejected and I wonder why.
I would argue that docker compose is not the same as dockerfile. That was the main reason for the edit, with additional minor (but valid) grammatical fixes. I also added bullet points to improve readability.
In order for me to mitigate similar mistakes in the future: what did I do wrong?

Issue: UVICORN reload inside docker container not working
Rejected Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36516719

It's a pretty minor edit; there is not really much difference between before and after.

Adding a bullet before "My docker compose" and "And my docker file" looks questionable: This markup don't make these items belonging to the single list (because of un-indented code between them). But otherwise the edit seems to be good: it fixes all grammar issues and even some semantical ones.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk May be minor, but that is not making it invalid, does it? And one difference is significant - I pointed it out as the first.

should I remove fluff. Minor edits don't make your edit invalid, but keep in mind that below 2k rep your edits need to be reviewed so they create additional workload for other people. If the edit is then only minor things and it doesn't even edit everything, that generally is rejected. Not because it is invalid, but because you need to be shocked into noticing it.

@PeterJames Because I did not notice. And also, what is necessary and what is not is mainly subjective. Moreover there is rule not to alter original meaning of the post, which I wanted to follow. Sometimes I delete it, you can check my editing history. Sometimes not, because I either do not see it or I don't think it's important, as in this case.

My advice: don't try to defend your suggested edit, the odds are not in your favor when you make honest mistakes, miss stuff you were not aware about, and get a suggested-edit rejected. Just let it go and take it as a learning opportunity. It happens. See if this helps: How do I make a good edit?

@Gimby I am aware of it, and I think that's why there is a 6 char rule with bypass check. I would also add that (in my point of view) SO is collaborative site - everyone does something. When you reject improving edit, because it was not sufficiently thorough and at the same time leave OP as it was before, you are not improving nor defending anything.

First of all, Jerry, I should of said this in my first comment: thank you for performing edits, people like you help make the site better for everyone. Now, as for the 6 character rule, that's just a heuristic to detect trivial edits. It's not great. Since two, and sometimes three reviewers, have to review your edit until you get enough reputation, your edits should be significant to justify this expense of reviewer time. Significant should not be measured in characters, but rather should be a subjective measure of post improvement.

You are correcting two minor spelling errors.
While commendable, if that's all you found worth correcting, please do not pad the edit with superfluous changes just to get to past the 6 char limit. That's going to annoy some reviewers.

I have now taken a more thorough look at the post, and I think it was easy to find more stuff worth correcting.

A couple minor fixes while leaving things unfixed? 
Padding the edit with unnecessary changes? 


I didn't do just that. Look carefully at that edit. Also, I did not circumvent 6 char rule, as I know it is not advisable. But it looks to me now that every smaller change is assessed as violation of 6 char rule, which I think it's not its purpose. In other words, it seems to me that some community members are making rules on their own.

Jerry, you said came here to learn what you did wrong, so you didn't make similar errors in the future. But when an explanation is offered, you reject it.

You don't have to believe what is said here. There are hundreds of similar meta posts which say exactly the same thing. And I don't think I'm paraphrasing, there literally are hundreds. Besides that, it's also in the help center. I quote: "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged; try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe". You may disagree about what makes a significant edit, but the onus is still on you to try and align with the common consensus.  Which again... existing meta posts area good guide.

@Gimby, I guess you are addressing Jerry, not me, right?

"But when an explanation is offered, you reject it." - well, if it's not true, he shouldn't accept it, should he? The part of your "explanation" that @Jerry objects to, that he added superfluous changes for the purpose of getting over the 6-char limit, is a claim about his intentions - about what was going on in his own mind. I would think he knows that better than we do! It seems outright rude to me, frankly, to scold him for not meekly accepting your assertions about his thought process, when he is the only one who was privy to it and you have no reason I can see to believe he's lying.

@yivi naturally. I was short on space for my rant :)

Some of your changes were objectively good but minor. Other changes were (not quite as objectively, but in my opinion and probably in the opinion of 90%+ of users) bad, and the result is an edit whose overall effect on the post is minor and at least arguably negative.
The good changes:

Correcting it's to its, i to I, and i'm to I'm
Adding a missing colon before the introduction of the second code block
Changing the second "my docker compose" to "my docker file" (at least a step in the right direction, though "my Dockerfile" would've been better)

The bad changes:

introducing a line break (but not a full paragraph break) in the middle of the third paragraph. Keeping it as one paragraph would've been fine. Breaking it into two paragraphs would also have been fine. But a paragraph with a line break is weird. In general, these kind of single line breaks shouldn't be used in prose (and are only useful in situations that are very rare in the context of Stack Overflow posts, such as for writing poems or mailing addresses)
making the words of prose introducing the code blocks be bulleted list items, but having the actual code blocks not be contained within these list items, creating weird formatting where there are two one-item bulleted lists in the post that each just contain a few words introducing some code that exists outside the list. (If those code blocks had been included in the list items, the change would still be superfluous, but perhaps not negative.)

This is an instance of a broad class edits - ones that include some minor improvements but also inflict some minor damage - that I always find annoying to review. Typically a slew of possible options are all legitimate and defensible:

simply approving
approving and editing to undo the bad changes
rejecting and editing to manually introduce the good changes
rejecting for "no improvement whatsoever"
rejecting with a custom reason pointing out the harmful changes

Which of those five options a reviewer judges is best is going to depend on that reviewer's own attitude and views on suggested edit reviews, on a slew of edit-specific factors such as whether they judge the edit to be good or bad for the post on net, whether the underlying post feels worth editing at all or editing it is a turd-polishing exercise, and whether the reason the bad changes are bad is obvious, and also on how much time the reviewer is willing and able to spend on the review at that particular moment. (Writing custom explanations or doing your own edit takes longer.)
I can't read their minds, but I'd guess the two reviewers you got thought the edit, on net, neither improved nor worsened the post, and that they didn't care about it enough to bother writing a custom explanation or doing an edit themselves. I also think this is probably fair enough in this case.
To avoid these kind of rejections, if you are going to make edits that basically consist of minor copyediting (which in and of themselves are absolutely fine and welcome!), just make sure all the individual minor changes you make are clearly good, and ideally mop up all the opportunities for such fixes that you see in the post.
